# homeomorphism between $\Bbb R^2/$~ and unit square

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that the quotient space $\Bbb R^2/$~, with equivalence relation ~ given by
 $$(x,y)\text~(x+n,y+m)\quad\quad\forall n, m \in \Bbb Z$$ is homeomorphic to the unit square under quotient topology.

Can anybody please give me a bit of hint please? I still cannot quite understand "quotient topology" and how the map between these two spaces would go.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: They're not homeomorphic. The first space is a torus, the second is a unit square. (Unless you are also quotienting the square, in which case you **can** get the torus).

Comment: Thanks a lot for response. I guess I wish to reduce R^2/~ to a "fundamental domain" which consists of the unit square with opposite sides identified. So I'm trying to show that this single square with quotient topology is homeomorphic to the whole plane quotiented by the relation ~ and given the quotient topology. Does that sound right? Thanks again! :)

Comment: The trouble is I kind of can see geometrically, but still cannot write down specific map how it really goes. Can you please give me a hand? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you also quotienting the square by the equivalence relation $(x,0)\sim (x,1)$ and $(0,y)\sim (1,y)$?

Comment: Sure, qoutienting the square in that way clear works, but how to write up the concrete map? Sorry I'm not good with details, that's the problem.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry it wasn't clear from the wording in the question.

Comment: Just send $(x+\mathbb Z, y+\mathbb Z) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ (where $x,y \in [0,1)$) to the equivalence class of $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2/{\sim}$ where $(x,y)\sim(x+n,y+m)$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and let $Y=([0,1]\times[0,1])/{\sim}'$ where $(x,0)\sim'(x,1)$ and $(0,y)\sim'(1,y)$.

Let $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ be given by $f([x]_{\sim},[y]_{\sim})=([\{x\}]_{\sim'},[\{y\}]_{\sim'})$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, where $\{-\}$ is the fractional part of a real number and the square brackets denote the equivalence class with respect to the indexed equivalence relation.

You have a few things to prove now.

- You have to show that $f$ is well-defined. That is, for $x'\in[x]_{\sim}$ and $y'\in[y]_{\sim}$ we have $([\{x\}]_{\sim'},[\{y\}]_{\sim'})=([\{x'\}]_{\sim'},[\{y'\}]_{\sim'})$.
- You have to show that $f$ is continuous.
- You have to show that $f$ is a bijection (i.e show that $f$ has a well-defined inverse).
- You have to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel, I can try to write down all details now. I wasn't sure what to do with square before as I wasn't sure how to deal with two equivalence relations at the same time. Now I will try to make more effort myself. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: If you're not too happy with multiple equivalence relations, I would suggest the following approach: Show that $X$ is homeomorphic to the space $T=S^1\times S^1$. Then, show that $Y$ is homeomorphic to $T$ as well. The map $f$ that I defined is a direct homeomorphism but adding an intermediary step via $T$ may be easier to handle if you're still learning this stuff.

Comment: Sure, that sounds very reasonable as well. In fact the original exercise was asking to show space X is homeomorphic to torus. I found that was difficult, so I thought to show X homeomorphic to square with quotient topology maybe easier, then since square with opposite sides identified is same as torus, then I'm done.